# Running a script using the runas command

Tags: windows

I need to run an install script as an administrator. I tried several things but none of them works

```
runas /user:Administrator install.bat
```

The shell asks for the password, then opens a new shell windows, and closes it right away without executing the script

```
runas /user:Administrator "call install.bat"
```

The shell asks for the password, then failed with an error

```
Unable to run - call install.bat
2: The system cannot find the file specified
```

What I don’t understand is that if I run the command `call install.bat` without the `runas` part, the script is ran. It failed for the commands that need admin credentials but that’s expected.

I have 2 questions:

- How to run the script as an administrator using the runas command?
- Could you explain why the following call is not working: `runas /user:Administrator "call install.bat"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cmd.exe` which is your vehicle to interpret `.cmd` and `.bat` files.

```
runas /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /K install.bat"
```

or

```
runas /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /C install.bat"
```

check `cmd.exe /?` for `/K` and `/C`.

Note: `/C` is more likely what you want.

Side-note after your comment: `runas` has a `/env` option:

```
/env              to use current environment instead of user's.
```

Comment: The issue is that it creates a new shell window, and clean up the current environment (working directory, custom environment variables)

Comment: @Sydney: be that as it is, this is the way to go. You could always write a wrapper script that calls `install.bat` after preparing the environment. Besides there is `runas /env` ... but you didn't even specify this side-condition in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Batch files are executed by the interpreter (cmd). In order to run script in privileged mode, you need cmd with raised priviledges. Try use cmd instead of call.