# Is there a way to run an .exe as a different user with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

Need to try and find a way to run an .exe as a different user, however, the user credentials must be hard coded into the script and not typed manually.

I have tried messing around with subprocess but this does not seem to be working as the scripts are breaking.

Comment: Any piece of code that you tried and what you tried?

Comment: The only way I know to do this is with psexec as in [this answer from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012750/11443248)

Comment: It's also worth noting that Windows makes it [intentionally difficult](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=37183) to hard code credentials into a script

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had a similar problem in Java and ended up using the PsExec tool and prompting the user for the password on execution.

However, depending on the situation, the windows command "runas" might do the job for you just fine.
Have a look at this question in case you are unfamiliar with it:
[Running a script using the runas command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587929/running-a-script-using-the-runas-command)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ctypes`, you can directly call the Windows `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function as in [this code](https://gist.github.com/liantian-cn/27c4836a2d96c902258d)